# Right align in react native flex box

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flexbox

How do I code following UI ? I want two views to be left aligned and one view to be right align, all three views in a row.
[image]

Here is my code, it displays all left-aligned

```
 <View style={{
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flex: 1,
    borderTopWidth: isIphoneX() ? 35 : 25,
    backgroundColor: color.PRIMARY_COLOR,
    padding: 20
}} >
    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        //some content
    </View>

    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column', justifyContent: 'center', paddingLeft:8 }}>
        //some content
    </View>

    <View style={{alignSelf:'flex-end' }}>
        //some content
    </View>
</View>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<View
  style={{
    flexDirection: "row",
    flex: 1,
    borderTopWidth: isIphoneX() ? 35 : 25,
    backgroundColor: color.PRIMARY_COLOR,
    padding: 20
  }}
>
  <View style={{ flexDirection: "column", justifyContent: "center" }}>
    //some content
  </View>

  <View
    style={{
      flexDirection: "column",
      justifyContent: "center",
      paddingLeft: 8
    }}
  >
    //some content
  </View>

  <View style={{ alignSelf: "flex-end" , position:'absolute' , right:5 }}>//some content</View>
</View>
```

Comment: Thanks :) This helps but by using position absolute, other UI issues came up. Is there any other way to do this without using position absolute?

Comment: @Dimalka Glad it helps :) Yes you have several ways of doing this. With your code easiest way is making position absolute and give right to it. Other than that you can devide base container view into two separate views and under that you can use flex-end with right sub view

Comment: @Dimalka if this solution works don't forget to make upvote and mark this answer as accepted correct answer btw :)

Comment: I'll try the solution in the comment, since your code too solves the problem, i have marked it as the answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

The simpler solution is to set an auto margin on one of the elements that surround the gap. This will cause the flexbox to schedule all free space to that gap.

```
 <View style={{
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flex: 1,
    borderTopWidth: isIphoneX() ? 35 : 25,
    backgroundColor: color.PRIMARY_COLOR,
    padding: 20
}} >
    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        //some content
    </View>

    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column', justifyContent: 'center', paddingLeft:8 }}>
        //some content
    </View>

    <View style={{marginLeft:'auto' }}>
        //some content
    </View>
</View>
```

This also works with multiple end-aligned items and without any absolute positioning.

Answer (score 0):

> Try This

```html
<View style={{
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flex: 1,
    padding: 20
}} >
    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row',flex:1 }}>
         <View>
           //some content
         </View>
         <View style={{marginLeft:10}}>
          //some content
         </View>
    </View>
    <View >
        //some content
    </View>
</View>
```